# Can't understand Return value in gaiaLineLocatePoint_r

Tags: spatialite

I am trying to develop a C application that finds the nearest point on a linestring from another point, in spatialite. I found 
the two API's ***gaiaLineLocatePoint_r*** and ***gaiaLineLocatePoint*** , but I am not able to understand their output. How to get the coordinates from them?

explanation of the API is [here](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/splite-doxy-4.2.0/gg__advanced_8h.html#a0f5449c63dae54dc3c289da19dcdaceb"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:
**Returns**
    the fraction [in the range 0.0 / 1.0] of **ln_geom** total length where the closest Point to **pt_geom** lays.

It means that if the returned value is 0.3 and the line "ln_geom" is 1000 meters long, then the point is at 300 m distance from the start point of the line. For resolving the coordinates of this closest points feed the fractional value (0.3) into **gaiaLineInterpolatePoint**.

However, you do not want to do it that way because there exists also **ClosestPoint** function. It is reported in the SQL document http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html but for some reason not in the API document.

Comment: Thanks. I am using ClosestPoint in my application and its working fine  :)